# Pass custom labels to HuggingFace data collator for LLM fine-tuning

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I want to fine-tune a decoder LLM with `prompt = input data + label` but I do not need the loss to be evaluated on input data, but only on the `label` part of the prompt.

So I set in my tokenization `inputs["labels"][:input_data_end] = [-100] * input_data_end`.

But then the data collator overwrites this for `mlm=False`, as the HF code in [`transformers/data/data_collator.py`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/data/data_collator.py#L758) goes (call from `transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False)`):

```py
def torch_call(self, examples: List[Union[List[int], Any, Dict[str, Any]]]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        # Handle dict or lists with proper padding and conversion to tensor.
        if isinstance(examples[0], Mapping):
            batch = self.tokenizer.pad(examples, return_tensors="pt", pad_to_multiple_of=self.pad_to_multiple_of)
        else:
            batch = {
                "input_ids": _torch_collate_batch(examples, self.tokenizer, pad_to_multiple_of=self.pad_to_multiple_of)
            }

        # If special token mask has been preprocessed, pop it from the dict.
        special_tokens_mask = batch.pop("special_tokens_mask", None)
        if self.mlm:
            batch["input_ids"], batch["labels"] = self.torch_mask_tokens(
                batch["input_ids"], special_tokens_mask=special_tokens_mask
            )
        else:
            labels = batch["input_ids"].clone(). # <--- OVERWRITING MMY LABELS HERE :(
            if self.tokenizer.pad_token_id is not None:
                labels[labels == self.tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100
            batch["labels"] = labels
        return batch
```

So the labels I set up first with the tokenizer are always overwritten.

Questions:

1. As I am tring to do somthing that is not allowed for `mlm=False` (`mlm=True` only gives random masks to labels), is my logic flawed for wanting to mask out `input data` for the loss?
2. If what I'm tryig to do makes sense, then should I write my own collator overwriting this method with `labels = batch["labels"].clone()` or there is a built-in approach to do so?

Version
`transformers==4.36.1`